# ember.js nested menu list

Tags: javascript, ember.js

here is my menuModel.coffee file

```
App.Menu = DS.Model.extend()
App.Menu.reopenClass
 find: ->
    model = Ember.A()
    x=
    [
        title: '数据总览'
        url: '#dashboard'
    ,
        title: '公司管理'
        url: 'companys'
        childs:
            [
                    title: '公司列表'
                    url: 'companys'
                ,
                    title: '创建公司'
                    url: 'companys/create'
                ,
                    title: '员工账号'
                    url: 'companys/users'
            ]
    ]
    data = JSON.parse(x)
    Ember.Logger.log(data)
    return data
```

and menuRoute.coffe file:

```
App.MenuRoute = Ember.Route.extend
model: ->
    App.Menu.find()
```

menu.hbs file:

```
{{#each pmenu in controller.data}}
<li>
  <a href="{{pmenu.url}}">
    <i class="fa fa-columns icon">
      <b class="bg-warning"></b>
    </i>
    <span class="pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down text"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up text-active"></i>
    </span>
    <span>{{pmenu.title}}</span>
  </a>
  {{#if pemnu.childs}}
  <ul>
    {{#each cmenu in pmenu.childs}}
    <li>
      <a href="#{{cmenu.url}}">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        <span>{{cmenu.title}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/if}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

i render my menu in my application.hbs using {{render 'menu' App.MenuView}},but there is nothing,i don't know to do make it show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues

```
<a href="{{pmenu.url}}">
```

needs to be

```
<a href="{{unbound pmenu.url}}"> or   <a {{bind-attr href=pmenu.url}}>
```

misspelled

```
{{#if pemnu.childs}}  ->   {{#if pmenu.childs}}
```

It looks like you're mixing Ember Data with plain Ember

```
App.Menu = Em.Object.extend(); // instead off DS

App.Menu.reopenClass({...
```

render you pass in the context, and it will create a controller and use the context to back the model

```
{{render 'menu' menuModel}}
```

Which route are you in rendering the menu?  the model hook is only called if you hit the menu route.  I'll make a couple examples

Without Ember Data, application template, using render

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eWecUbif/1/edit

With Ember Data and bind-attr

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/17/edit

Comment: thank you,but i have a menu controller,because i want this menu show in all pages,so i use the render in applicaiton.hbs,but it not work,and the debug info is :"Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed App.MenuController, but it should have been an ArrayController "

Comment: Your menu controller should be Ember.ArrayController.extend({

Comment: thanks,should i change the setupController into the menu route?and the {{render "menu" menu}} in application.hbs doesn't work,here is the gist address: https://gist.github.com/magicshui/7975365 i am not sure how to make this menu show on every route

Comment: The code will never use the menu route, unless it's part of the url.  You'll need to get the menu info in the application route since you're using it there.

Comment: sorry,still have a problem,i move the setupController into application's route,but the error log is:Assertion failed: Error while loading route: Error: Object in path men could not be found or was destroyed.

Comment: based on your gist the menu portion works http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eWecUbif/3/edit

Comment: thanks,it sames a strange problem in my local machine,i will check out later,thanks for your help:)

Comment: finally solved this problem, it seems that i need to add `mennu: null` into application controller,thus controller.set('model',App.Menu.find()) can works correct!